# NSMutableArray not being saved

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to insert objects (NSNumbers) into an NSMutable array, but when I check it, the objectAtElement always returns 0.

```
NSNumber *indexNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexInt];
[last100 insertObject:indexNum atIndex:prevCount];
NSLog(@"Entry #%d : %d", prevCount, (int)[last100 objectAtIndex:prevCount]);
prevCount++;
```

`indexInt` is coming in through the method, I already checked it and its valid. `indexNum` has also been checked and matches `indexInt`. The problem is `NSLog(@"Entry #%d : %d", prevCount, (int)[last100 objectAtIndex:prevCount]);` which always returns

`2012-01-08 14:08:11.551 ThoughtSpreader[20746:fb03] Entry #9 : 0` The entry number will change, but the 0 is always there.

Oh, I also checked [last100 count] after every time I insert something new into it, and it always returns 0, so I believe its a problem with how I'm inserting something into the NSMutable array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your count always returns 0 the likelihood is you haven't actually instantiated your `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];

NSLog(@"%lu", [array count]); // Count => 1

//-------

array = nil;

[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]; // Calling methods on nil is a no-op

NSLog(@"%lu", [array count]); // Count => 0
```

Updated `%d` to `%lu` thanks to @markhunte - it's hard to remember the finer details without testing it

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
[[last100 objectAtIndex:prevCount] intValue]
```

instead of

`(int)[last100 objectAtIndex:prevCount]` - this explict conversion won't work.

[... intValue] is the message of NSNUmber which converts it to [int](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Makes sense, but didn't actually help :/

Comment: @Chris have you checked `indexInt` before you insert it?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, I've checked it before and after

Answer (score 0):

[`NSNumber`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is an object, you can't just cast it to an `int`.  Use `intValue`:

```
NSLog(@"Entry #%d : %d", prevCount, [[last100 objectAtIndex:prevCount] intValue]);
```

Comment: Or you can just use the `%@` object format specifier. `NSLog(@"Entry #%d : %@", prevCount, [last100 objectAtIndex:prevCount]);`